# Making custom command behave like ":echo" with respect to quotes

Tags: vimscript, command

This command works without errors:

```
:echo v:oldfiles->copy()->filter('v:val =~# "txt$"')
```

(see `:h method`, `:h v:oldfiles`, `:h v:val` and `:h =~#`)

I want to create a custom command / function combination that wraps the `:echo` and still accepts the `v:oldfiles->copy()->filter('v:val =~# "txt$"')` argument like in the `:echo` did.

I have this:

```
command! -bar -complete=expression -nargs=1 Foo call FooFunc(<args>)

function! FooFunc(x) 
    echo a:x
endfunction
```

However, invoking `:Foo v:oldfiles->copy()->filter('v:val =~# "txt$"')` results in the error:

```
E115: Missing quote: 'v:val =~#
```

How can I make it work like the `:echo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For this particular task it's much much easier to do simply

   ```
   :filter /txt$/ oldfiles
   ```
2. The error is due to `-bar` argument: the quote is parsed like a comment sign, and so the rest of the command is lost (see `:h :command-bar`, `:h :quote`).

Either always escape all quotes (and bars) with backslashes, or remove `-bar` argument from the command definition.

Comment: Wouldnt it also need to be `execute 'echo' a:x`?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Here we have `FooFunc(<args>)`, i.e. the argument is non-quoted. Hence an expression gets evaluated upon function call and no `execute` is needed. Of course, that could result in some other errors, such as `:Foo 1,2` --> `Too many parameters`, etc.etc.

Comment: Huh! That's pretty interesting! But `-bar` is about recognizing `|` as a command separator, what does `"` as a comment character has to do with it? Why are these two connected? (I don't doubt that this is correct and indeed how it works, just wondering why it's that way...)

Comment: For instance, `:echo "a" | echo "b"` works just fine... So it's akin to a user-defined command that has `-bar`, but it doesn't take `"` as comments... Yes, user-defined commands are somewhat different from built-ins, but still wondering why this is the way it is.

Comment: @filbranden That's how it works: in a user command one can only switch on/off both simultaneously using "-bar". Not a case for internal commands such as :echo. So, yes, this is really frustrating :-((